# SABER DURACION CANCION CON MIXER DE PYGAME (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Quiero saber la duracion de la musica introducida

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
 from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from pygame import mixer 
    from mutagen.id3 import ID3
    import os
    from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
    listofsongs = []
        def seleccionar_carpeta():
          directorio = filedialog.askdirectory()
          os.chdir(directorio)
          for files in os.listdir(directorio):
              if files.endswith(".mp3"):
                  realdir = os.path.realpath(files)
                  audio = ID3(realdir)
                  realnames.append(audio['TIT2'].text[0])
                  listofsongs.append(files)
          mixer.init()
          mixer.music.load(listofsongs[0])
          actualizar()
```

Quiero que aqui aparezca el tiempo de la cancion:

```
duracion = Label(text='--:--')
```

Y tambien lo que lleva de reproduccion
He estado mirando en la pagina oficial y he encontrado que con `get_length` se puede hacer pero creo que solo en terminal https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pygame.mixer.Sound` solo funciona con OGG o WAV. `pygame.mixer.music` soporta MP3, aunque de forma limitada:

> Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux.
>
> Consider using OGG instead.

### Obtener el tiempo total

Con archivos MP3 no es una tarea sencilla con PyGame, no obstante, dado que usas `mutagen`, es muy simple obtener la duración total con dicha librería:

```
audio = mutagen.File("file_path")
longitud = audio.info.length
minutos, segundos = divmod(longitud, 60)
minutos, segundos = int(minutos), int(segundos)
```

### Obtener progreso durante la reprodución

Puedes usar [pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_pos), pero teniendo en cuenta que solo representa el tiempo que ha estado la música reproduciéndose. Debes tenerlo en cuenta si implementas alguna funcionalidad
que permita  reanudar o comenzar la reproducción desde un punto determinado del audio.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de reproductor:

```
import sys
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import mutagen
import pygame


def load():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Selecciona un archivo",
        filetypes = (("Audio Files", "*.mp3"),
                     ("Audio Files", "*.ogg")
                     )
        )
    if not file_path:
        current_time.set("--:--")
        total_time.set("--:--")
        file.set("Seleccione un archivo mp3")
        return

    file.set(os.path.basename(file_path))

    # Tiempo total
    audio = mutagen.File(file_path)
    total_length = audio.info.length
    tm, ts = divmod(total_length, 60)
    tm, ts = int(tm), int(ts)
    total_time.set(f"{tm:02}:{ts:02}")

    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(file_path)
    repr_btn.config(state="normal")


def play():
    global state

    if state == "stop":
        state = "play"
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        root.after(0, update_state)
        repr_btn.config(text=" Detener  ")
        pausar_btn.config(state="normal")
        pausar_btn.config(text="  Pausar  ")

    else:
        state = "stop"
        repr_btn.config(text="Reproducir")
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
        pausar_btn.config(state="disabled")
        pausar_btn.config(text="  Pausar  ")


def pause():
    global state

    if state == "pause":
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        pausar_btn.config(text="  Pausar  ")
        state = "play"

    elif state == "play":
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        pausar_btn.config(text=" Reanudar ")
        state = "pause"


def update_state():
    global state

    pos_time = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
    if pos_time == -1 or state == "stop":
        current_time.set(f"00:00")
        state = "stop"
        pausar_btn.config(state="disabled")
        repr_btn.config(text="Reproducir")
        return

    s = pos_time // 1000
    m, s = divmod(s, 60)
    m, s = int(m), int(s)
    current_time.set(f"{m:02}:{s:02}")
    root.after(500, update_state)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("450x130")

state = "stop"
current_time = tk.StringVar(root, "--:--")
total_time = tk.StringVar(root, "--:--")
file = tk.StringVar(root, "Seleccione un archivo mp3")

tk.Label(root, text="Archivo: ").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NE)
tk.Label(root, textvariable=file).grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
tk.Label(root, text="Tiempo total: ").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.NE)
tk.Label(root, textvariable=total_time).grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
tk.Label(root, text="Tiempo reproducido: ").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.NE)
tk.Label(root, textvariable=current_time).grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)

abrir_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Abrir", command=load)
abrir_btn.grid(row=3, column=0)
repr_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Reproducir", command=play, state="disabled")
repr_btn.grid(row=3, column=1)
pausar_btn = tk.Button(root, text="  Pausar  ", command=pause, state="disabled")
pausar_btn.grid(row=3, column=2)

root.grid_rowconfigure(3, pad=30)
root.mainloop()
sys.exit()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]